# How to run timer build using angularjs even the browser is closed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my angularjs project I have build a timer functionality using the $timeout feature of Angular libarary. The timer is working fine . but I need the functionality that even if the browser window is closed the timer should run . It will be only stop when I will forcefully close it using the stop button. How to accomplish that . Please give some idea.

Thanks
Utpal

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage:

```
localStorage.timer = localStorage.timer + 1; // just an exampe
localStorage.ctime = // add the current time you updated the timer.
```

then on your $timer - just check if theres a difference between localStorage.ctime & the real current time, if so - update the timer.